# how to change digits language in mathjax

Tags: fonts, mathjax

We have used mathjax to our website (java- GWT) to render formulas and it works pretty well, but the problem is that we need to show the numerals in persian/arabic script to our users.

I have to mention we have more than 100k multiple choice questions and over 5k articles in our site which have formulas to render.

Answer (score 1):

This is the Java way of doing it. I answered this as you have a java tag. I dont know about mathjax. I hope you can implement this logic in your code.

Arabic for 01232456789 = \u06f0\u06f1\u06f2\u06f3\u06f4\u06f5\u06f6\u06f7\u06f8\u06f9.

We deal with each character as a char instead of int. So, convert the number into character string and then use this function. It should serve your purpose.

```
private static String decimalToArabic(String number) {
    char[] chars = new char[number.length()];
    for(int i=0;i<number.length();i++) {
        char ch = number.charAt(i);
        switch(ch) {
            case '\u06F0' : chars[i] = '0';
                            break;
            case '\u06F1' : chars[i] = '1';
                            break;
            case '\u06F2' : chars[i] = '2';
                            break;
            case '\u06F3' : chars[i] = '3';
                            break;
            case '\u06F4' : chars[i] = '4';
                            break;
            case '\u06F5' : chars[i] = '5';
                            break;
            case '\u06F6' : chars[i] = '6';
                            break;
            case '\u06F7' : chars[i] = '7';
                            break;
            case '\u06F8' : chars[i] = '8';
                            break;
            case '\u06F9' : chars[i] = '9';
                            break;
        }
    }
    return new String(chars);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I need to do it using mathjax, as there are lots of digits ine the page that I dont want them to be changed. I only need changing digits in mathematics formula

Answer (score 1):

In order to access the Persian digits, you would need to use references to the Unicode positions for those glyphs.  The Persian digits are at U+06F0 to U+06F9 (and the Arabic digits are U+0660 to U+0669).  Therefore you could use  `\unicode{0x6F2}` to produce the Persian glyph for 2 (۲).  The web fonts available in MathJax do not include glyphs for the Arabic or Persian digits, so there is no guarantee that the reader will be able to view this symbol, however.  You can improve the odds by including suggested fonts that include the symbol.  It looks like Arial and Times New Roman both include the Arabic and Persian characters, so

```
\unicode['Times New Roman',Arial]{x6F2}
```

would likely make it possible for most viewers to see the characters you expect.  Of course, you could create macros like `\0`, `\1`, `\2`, etc. to make it easier to type.

Alternatively, if you want to have "123" display as "۱۲۳" automatically, that can be done by adding the following

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  "HTML-CSS": {
    undefinedFamily: "'Times New Roman',Arial,STIXGeneral,'Arial Unicode MS',serif",
    noReflows: false
  }
});
MathJax.Hub.Register.StartupHook("HTML-CSS Jax Ready", function () {
  var REMAP = MathJax.OutputJax["HTML-CSS"].FONTDATA.REMAP;
  var ZERO = 0x6F0;     // use 0x660 for Arabic, 0x6F0 for Persian
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {REMAP[0x30+i] = ZERO+i}
});
</script>
```

to your page just BEFORE the script that loads MathJax.js itself.  This will remap all the digits 0 through 9 to their Persian (or Arabic if you change `ZERO = 0x6F0` to `ZERO = 0x660`) counterparts.

Note that this only affects the HTML-CSS output.  A similar configuration would work for SVG output if you change the HTML-CSS to SVG throughout.  But this will NOT change the results for NativeMML output (the original `\unicode{}` approach would work in all three output formats, however).